# Blender file from 2018 renders no shading in Blender 4.0.2

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, lighting

I've opened a blender file, I made in 2018 in Blender 4.0.2. It is some 3D text. But when I render it, there are not materials and no lighting apparently. Maybe it is just transparent background.

I've added a sphere to confirm, but it renders also with background blocks.

How do I get it to render materials.
Also, I don't see any settings to change light color and intensity. Where are those settings. (I haven't used blender since then and the tutorial video I just watched also did not explain it)

See screenshot of new render and original old render:
4.0.2 render
[image: 4.0.2 render]

2018 render
[image: 2018 render]

UPDATE: I just opened a clean general scene and it renders the same:
The standard scene:

[image: Standard scene]

UPDATE: I installed blender 2.79B and everything works OK. Maybe it is just my 10 years old graphics card: Ati Radeon HD7770.

Comment: Blender versions from 2018 are very different to version 4 and the Blend files from that time are not guaranteed to open correctly in Blender 4.

Comment: It seems the alpha-rendering goes wrong. the image is transparent and the background is opaque. I just opened a clean general scene and it renders the same: See updated post.

Comment: Enabling Render->Film->Transparent, just makes the entire output render transparent!

Comment: That setting just renders any background image you may have (such as a HDRI image for lighting) as transparent. What render engine are you using and can you share your Blend file?  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/313550/edit) your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: Actually, I installed Blender 2.79B and everything worked normally.
Maybe the problem is my 10-years old graphics card: Ati Radeon HD7770.

Comment: Your graphics card was released in 2012 so it's very unlikely that it will be supported in Blender 4!